# Website form populated from mySQL database, how to return data

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to write a wordpress plugin and I have hit a bump. I am new to PHP (coded in Java before) and javascript so I am not sure whats the best way to solve my problem.

**The Background**
I have some data in a mySQL DB that I am using (each row has a unique ID and some other information I have added). I am able to search the DB using

```
    $headss = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}costumesdb WHERE location = 'head'", ARRAY_A);
```

And display some of the information to the user using (this is one of 5 different drop-downs but they are all created in the same way)

```
    Head: <select name="head">
<?php foreach ($heads as $head) { ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $head['pieceName'] ?>"><?php echo $head['shopName'] . " - " . $head['pieceName'] ?></option>
<?php } ?>
    </select>
```

For the moment I want the user to be restricted to choosing information that is already in the system.

**The problem**
The DB contains 2 pieces of information that the user does not need to know to fill in the form (a website URL and a picture URL). I need these 2 pieces of information once the form is submitted (I need to write some more code for that) to the server which spits out another page with the 2 URL's in it.

Whats the best way to send the data back to a PHP script? Am I able to access the row of data that the user has selected in the drop down and send the unique ID for that row back or do I need to do something else?

Edit:
This is the script that I am using to submit the code:
    
        $('#createacostume').form({
        success:function(data){
        $.messager.alert('Info', data, 'info');
        }
        });
        '

And then the page to display the information returned is:
    $cname = $_POST['cname'];
    $head = $_POST['head'];
echo "Data Returned
 Name $cname 
 head $head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking:

User has to choose an item from a drop down and submit a form. You have to display the website URL and the image for that item in a second page.  You want to know how this is typically accomplished.

If that's the case, you should pass the row id of the item to the second page like so:

```
<option value="<?php echo $head['ROW_ID'] ?>"><?php echo $head['shopName'] . " - " . $head['pieceName'] ?></option>
```

Then use the ROW_ID in the second page to access the data from the database and print out the website URL and the image.

Comment: I think this might work. I will test it asap and let you know.

Comment: @Gathris : Did it work for you?  Do you need further assistance?

Comment: Yes. Sorry for the late response.

Answer (score 0):

Submit the first form (without the two field), INSERT the data into the database, get the ID of insert.

Pass the ID to the next page which would set the ID into a hidden form field (or GET or POST parameter, plenty of choices) of the new form (with the two fields and just UPDATE the database upon submitting the second form.

If you like to show the original data in the second form, just pull the data from the database  and use it to render the form instead of passing just the ID into a hidden field.

Comment: What If the user wants to reuse some data in the DB? I get what your saying about sending the id of the insert but the final page is not a form. Its a wordpress post with extra css and the (total of) 10 URL's. The idea is that the user can choose some pictures to go in the new post and those pictuers are links to websites.

Comment: Not sure I understood fully, but can't you just pull the data from the DB and use it in the post?

Comment: The post is created from the selections that the user chooses but those choices may already be in the DB. I was planning to handle the upload at another time.